# Why shutil move not working if folder exist

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
archive = "archive"
if not os.path.exists(archive):
    os.mkdir(archive)
gzfile = "lalala.gz"
dest = join(archive, gzfile)
shutil.move(gzfile, dest)
```

And is behaving quite strange.
Shutil.move works when the directoy does not exist --> thats mean my script create the folder (in current directoy) and move the gzfile to archive. But when the directoy exist (because i ran my script one time already) shutil.move does not move gzfile to the archive folder. Why the diference in behaviour here

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in all scenarios, but you have to change your join function to use the os.path join function

```
import shutil, os

archive = "archive"
if not os.path.exists(archive):
    os.mkdir(archive)
gzfile = "lalala.gz"
dest = os.path.join(archive, gzfile) # add os.path.join()
shutil.move(gzfile, dest)
```

Also, be sure to recreate the "lalala.gz" file after you have executed the script. It won't move it if it's not there

Comment: Thanks for u answer! it was a linux bug, shutil copy instead  moving. Strage is that I cannot see the original file even after using ls -al, but it is there because after restart the interface ask me if  I want to replace the file. I said "yes"  I want to replace the "non_existant" file and it works now.